# powershell use employeeID to get sAMAccount information

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with employee ID's, these ID's are tied to AD Accounts, I need to get the AD User information from the employee ID and export them to a csv file. Below is the script I wrote, it works if I run it without the export-csv switch, I have tried adding a pipe but the error I get from that is pipe cannot be empty.

```
    $userIDs = Import-CSV "C:\Users_.csv"
    foreach($userID in $userIDs)
    { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($userID.EmployeeID)" -Properties SAMAccountName 
    }

    Export-CSV "C:\UserResults.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single pipeline:

```
Import-CSV "C:\Users_.csv" | 
  ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($_.EmployeeID)" } |
    Export-CSV "C:\UserResults.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Note the use of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* instead of the `foreach` *statement* - only the cmdlet can be used in a pipeline.
(Somewhat confusingly, the cmdlet has an *alias* also named `foreach`; whether the statement or the cmdlet is used is implied by the context (parsing mode).)

Inside the script block `{ ... }` passed to `ForEach-Object`, automatic variable `$_` represents the input object at hand.

Also note that `Get-ADUser` outputs objects that have property `SAMAccountName`  by default, so you needn't request it explicitly.